# Which JBoss version should be choose?

Tags: performance, jboss, application-server

We are now developing and running a java web application under JBoss 4.2.3 for many years. We using Struts 1 + Hibernate 2  as the framework. We don't using any EJB things.

My question is should we upgrade our runtime platform to newly JBoss version? Which version is the best on performance side. Is JBoss 5.x a good candidate?

Thanks.

Tang

Comment: We find it tricky to answer questions like this here. New versions of middleware tend to be released as they are pitched to be 'better' than the old versions, but can your new hardware run it, can your software run on it? Will you require expensive testing and rewriting to move to the new version? No need to answer my rhetorical questions. Please read the site faq.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme answer this from a different angle.

It is not so much the version of the app server as is the version of the JVM. JBoss 4.2.3, if I remember correctly, runs on JVM 1.5.x, which is 32bit. The latest JVM being 1.6.x, 64bit -- with considerable enhancements and improvements over the 32bit version.

Also, the performance you are going to be more interested in is that of your app and not the app server.

My suggestion is go 64bit on the JVM, and the latest on the app server -- not for performance, but bug fixes, features etc. Then, benchmark, load test, and tune your app to improve performance.